# List top Nodes / siblings in maya outliner

Tags: python, maya

Is there a way to only list top nodes in the `outliner`, without traversing all the depths?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.listRelatives("master", noIntermediate=True)
```

I was kind of expecting that there will be a key like `world` to search the topnodes in the outliner.

Example Outliner:

```
#--- pSphere1
#---group1
 ------box1
#pSphere2
```

I only want `pSphere1`, `pSphere2` and `group1` not the children of those.

Comment: ABsolutely....let me fix that.

Comment: Did you want to get the top node from the given selection, or just list all the top nodes?

Comment: All Top nodes, basically everything under 'world'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

`cmds.ls(assemblies=True)`

With your example, it will return the following:
`[u'persp', u'top', u'front', u'side', u'pSphere1', u'group1', u'pSphere2']`

You can filter out the cameras either by name, their object type (camera), or using `cmds.camera` to determine if it's a default camera:

`cmds.camera("front", q=True, startupCamera=True) # Would return True.`

Comment: Must have missed that, I've already  went too far by using `openmaya` and traversing through the first depth, I'll see if this will get slow speedwise compared to iterating the graph. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What I've realized, if i wanted to get exact types. the query doesn't hold up `MC.ls(assemblies=True, exactType="transform")` that will return everything.

Comment: Yes, I suggest using `cmds.listRelatives(shapes=True, type="")` if you're trying to filter out certain types. And remember, something like `persp` is still a transform, it's its shape that is a `camera`.

Comment: That's true, so what were you expecting to put in `type` then?

Comment: You mean in `listRelatives`? It'll return any shapes under the given transform that matches the type you supplied. If you mean `type` or `exactType` for `ls`, then it's suppose to return you objects that match the type you supplied, but I don't think it works together properly with assemblies parameter in `ls`. That's why you may need to loop through what assemblies spits out and use `listRelatives` or any other command to filter out what you don't want. I'm not sure why you unchecked my answer, as it does what your question is asking for. (maybe edit your question if type matters)